# "Ну(,) если уж ты не понимаешь..." — нужна запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

**Ну(,) если уж ты не понимаешь...**

Нужна ли здесь запятая? Какое правило используется?

Answer (score 3):

**Возможны оба варианта.** Слово НУ может быть частицей или междометием, поэтому окончательно выбор можно сделать при наличии полного текста.

**Междометия** выделяются запятыми, но их нужно **отличать от частиц**, имеющих усилительное значение. Часто (в том числе, в приведенном примере) это связано **с авторским выбором и проверяется наличием паузы.**

1) Частица: **Ну если уж ты не понимаешь...**

Здесь ударение может падать на "ты" (если тЫ не понимаешь, то кто же поймет) или на глагол "понимаешь". После НУ пауза не делается.

2) **Междометие: Ну, если уж ты не понимаешь...**

Междометие НУ(выделение паузой и запятой)   чаще выражает побуждение к дальнейшему действию, например: "Ну, давай плясать! Становись!" В этом случае это действие должно быть как-то обозначено при развитии темы.

Примеры из Нацкорпуса:

**Ну если** уж он так скажет, то ты ему тоже можешь сказать: а кому нужны твои книжки! [Владимир Войнович. Москва 2042 (1986)]

― **Ну, если** уж и ты так думаешь, то мы сейчас же отправляемся обратно! [Ефим Чеповецкий. Непоседа, Мякиш и Нетак (1989)]